# Detect hard press iOS with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, touch

So I was wondering with the new hard press detection on newer iOS devices, is it possible to detect such a thing without being an actual app?

By this, I mean is it possible to detect using JavaScript or something of the sorts. To be frank, I don't see anything relating to this question on SO, at least as far as web programming is concerned.

To state my hypothesis, I doubt it's possible at all as I'm sure it's a hardware event that just isn't passed forward through safari (or whatever browser) to the JavaScript engine.

Simply a curious question, any answers are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Emanuel

**EDIT: So here's the tl;dr of that other answer: No, not for iOS; only for desktop with the ForceTouch trackpad. This will save some people some time. Here's the catch: according to [this](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/ios9-safari-for-web-developers), the Safari app supports it using a new API, but other browsers are yet to support it.**

Comment: You would just need to run the JS in a browser that supported it. AFAIK from my experience, JS is limited to whatever its environment supplies.

Comment: [This may be what you're looking for.](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/ios9-safari-for-web-developers)

Comment: Ah yep. That's the answer there. I didn't know that it went by the name 3d touch, no biggie.

Comment: Actually that answer is outdated and therefore incorrect. A proper answer is posted in an edit above.

Answer (score 1):

I did not test it, because I don't have an iPhone 6s or a MacBook with ForceTouch-Trackpad, but it should work.

There is a demo on GitHub: https://github.com/freinbichler/3d-touch